# Binding Dictionary<string, int> to

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

This is my Enum

```
public enum Works
{
    [Description("Admin")]
    Admin,
    [Description("Chưa Set")]
    UnSetted,
    [Description("Vào - Ra")]
    InOut,
    [Description("Ra - Vào")]
    OutIn
}
```

This is my ViewModel

```
 public class DivisionViewModel : ViewModel<IDivisionView>
{
    private IEnumerable<Account> accounts;
    private ICommand confirmCommand;
    private Dictionary<string, int> works;
....
}
```

I convert the enum to get a Dictionary and get accounts like this

```
this.divisionViewModel.Accounts = Root.Accounts;

this.divisionViewModel.Works = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Works))
                                   .Cast<Works>()
                                   .ToDictionary(t => Tools.GetEnumDescription((Works)t), t => (int)t);
```

Here is my WPF DataGrid

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding FullName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
                                Header="Tên nhân viên" Width="*" ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextCellElementStyle}"
                                EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource TextCellEditingStyle}"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

How can I bind the `this.divisionViewModel.Works` to the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`?
p/s: I want my user to change the Work directly on the DataGrid. I have seachred on SO. But nobody seems to talk about binding Dictionary to a DataGridComboBoxColumn.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is empty:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Works.Keys}">
```

is because the `ComboBox` will have the current `Account` bound as a ViewModel. You need to bind to the `DataGrid`'s ViewModel, and that's where `RelativeSource` comes in handy:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn  ItemsSource="{Binding Works.Keys, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
```

**Note:** Check your Output Window in Visual Studio, you'll see Binding errors telling you that they can't find a Property named `Work` in an `Account`

Comment: It is not work. It show a list of empty selection. I have tried to put another combobox outside the datagird and bindind to -> It work.

Comment: Oops sorry, I read your ViewModel wrong. Let me edit my answer